# Why does TSynEdit not detect Tab key pressed?

Tags: delphi, synedit

This is my first question, I hope it will be a well constructed one.

I'm currently using Delphi 10.4 Community Edition and I installed SynEdit through the GetIt Package Manager.

The problem I'm facing is the following: I created a VCL form, dropped a TSynEdit in it and launched the application. The problem is that if I press the `TAB` or `SHIFT+TAB`, nothing happens. I tried to put breakpoints in the following methods of `TSynEdit`:

- `CommandProcessor`
- `ExecuteCommand`
- `DoTabKey`

and the debugger never enters them while pressing those keys.

I then looked at the `Keystrokes` property of my `TSynEdit` control and, although the keystroke for `TAB` is defined, I think that the shortcut is "fake". What I mean is that if I try to modify what is associated to the `ecTab` command and manually choose the shortcut value, nor `Tab` or `Shift+Tab` are present in the listbox.

Did anyone ever experienced a problem like this? If so, how did you manage to solve it?

PS: Indentation works with other shortcuts, such as `CTRL+SHIFT+I/U`.

Comment: Have you tried setting the WantTabs property to True?

Comment: @KeithMiller You were right! As usual, the problems with which one loses the most time are the simplest. I'm still confused as to why the TAB key is not selectable in the shortcuts listbox though.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by [Keith Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72707960/why-does-tsynedit-not-detect-tab-key-pressed/72714506#comment128433709_72707960), it was as simple as setting to `True` the property `WantTabs` for the `TSynEdit` control.

Still, if anyone knows why the `TAB` and `SHIFT+TAB` shortucts don't appear in the listbox of selectable shortcuts, please let us know.